How to access the input box by clicking an object?
This is how my layout is:

I want the user to be able to click any of the circles, which will allow them to be able to put in a player name and player number, which will then be displayed on the lineup
This is my code:
const [formation, setFormation] = useState(
localStorage.getItem("formation") === null
  ? {
    squad: {
      gk: 1,
      df: [2, 3, 4, 5],
      cdm: [6, 7],
      cm: [8],
      cam: [9, 10],
      fw: [11]
    },
    style: {
      color: `#${state.homeTeamColor}`,
      numberColor: `#${state.homeTeamNumberColor}`,
      nameColor: `#${state.nameColor}`,
    }
  }
  : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formation"))
 )

const [newPlayerName, setNewPlayerName] = useState("")
const [newPlayerNumber, setNewPlayerNumber] = useState("");
const addPlayer = () => {    
const [newPlayerName, setNewPlayerName] = useState("")
const [newPlayerNumber, setNewPlayerNumber] = useState("");

const handleNewPlayerNameChange = (evt) => {
    setNewPlayerName(evt.target.value);
  }

const handleNewPlayerNumberChange = (evt) => {
    setNewPlayerNumber(evt.target.value);
  }

const editNewPlayer = () => {
    if (position === "gk") {
      setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
        ...homeTeam,
        [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
      }));
    } else if (position === "df") {
      setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
        ...homeTeam,
        squad: {
          ...homeTeam.squad,
          [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
        }
      }));
    }
 else {
     setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
       ...homeTeam,
       squad: {
         ...homeTeam.squad,
         [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
      }
    }));
    }
  }


const addNewPlayer = () => {
    setError(null); 
    if (newPlayerName === "") {
      setError("Player Name required!");
    }
    else if (newPlayerNumber === "") {
      setError("Player Number required!");
    }
    else {
      let playerObj = {
        id: nanoid(),
        name: newPlayerName,
        color: `#${state.homeTeamColor}`,
        numberColor: `#${state.homeTeamNumberColor}`,
        namecolor: `#${state.nameColor}`
      };
      if (playerPosition === "gk") {
        playerObj.onClick = () =>
          editNewPlayer("gk", playerObj.id);
        setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
          ...homeTeam,
          squad: { ...homeTeam.squad, gk: playerObj }
        }));

      } else if (playerPosition === "df") {
        playerObj.onClick = () =>
          editNewPlayer("df", playerObj.id);
        setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
          ...homeTeam,
          squad: {
            ...homeTeam.squad,
            df: [...homeTeam.squad.df, playerObj]
          }
        }));
      }

      else {
        playerObj.onClick = () =>
          editNewPlayer("fw", playerObj.id);
        setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
          ...homeTeam,
          squad: {
            ...homeTeam.squad,
            fw: [...homeTeam.squad.fw, playerObj]
          }
        }));
      }
    }
    setNumber(number + 1);
  }

  return (
  <>
    <div className={showtab === 2 ? "col-2" : "preBuilt"} >
        <div className="formRow" id="formRowColor">
          <div className="formError">
            {error !== null ? (
              <div
                className="alert alert-danger p-2 m-0"
                role="alert"
              >
                {error}
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="playerName"><b>Player Name</b></label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="playerName"
              placeholder="Player Name"
              name="playerName"
              value={newPlayerName}
              onChange={handleNewPlayerNameChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label className="playerNumber" htmlFor="playerNumber"><b>Player Number</b></label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="playerNumber"
              placeholder="Player Number"
              value={newPlayerNumber}
              onChange={handleNewPlayerNumberChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            <label className="col-form-label">
              <b>Lineup Formations</b>
            </label>
            <div className="buttonGroup">
              <button className="lineupbtn" onClick={() => handlelineup(2)}>4-3-3</button>
              <button className="lineupbtn" onClick={() => handlelineup(5)}>4-2-3-1</button>
            </div>
            <div className="buttonGroup">
              <button className="lineupbtn" onClick={() => handlelineup(3)}>4-4-2</button>
              <button className="lineupbtn" onClick={() => handlelineup(6)}>4-2-2-2</button>
            </div>
            <div className="buttonGroup">
              <button className="lineupbtn" onClick={() => handlelineup(4)}>3-4-3</button>
              <button className="lineupbtn" onClick={() => handlelineup(7)}>4-4-1-1</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="buttonPosition">
          <button className="addButton" onClick={addNewPlayer}>
            Add Player
          </button>
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>    
   <div ref={contentRef} className=" col-9" >
        <div className={showlineup === 1 ? "col9" : "div1Hide"}>
          <SoccerLineUp
            size={"fill"}
            color={"green"}
            pattern={"lines"}
            homeTeam={homeTeam}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={showlineup === 2 ? "col9" : "div2Hide"}  >
          <SoccerLineUp
            size={"fill"}
            color={"green"}
            pattern={"lines"}
            homeTeam={formation}
          />
        </div>
      <>
      )

With this code, I am unable to click on the circles on the lineup. I need help determining how to be able to click on the circle and when I do, to see if logic I wrote in the addNewPlayer() function works.

where is the code for the circle components?  have you put onClick events/handlers on them?  is the problem that the click event is not firing?  what connects the circles to the addNewPlayer form?  are you passing in any position data to your addNewPlayer form?  all you've shown is the code that handles the form.  we need more information on its relation to the circles and what your specific problem is.

@sparkJ I added the code for the circle components at the beginning

what i need to see in order to try to help is your circle components and what the current click logic is.  for example:
const Circle = () => { const handleTheClick = (e) => { // handle }; return (<div onClick={handleTheClick}>Circle 1</div>) }

@sparkJ i downloaded a react soccer lineup from github which came with the lineup pitch and circles. So, I manually created the lineups in formation. I didn't create the circles on my end. For the logic for clicking the circle, I added some in the addNewPlayer function. I'm not sure if the logic is right.

i believe i found the github you mentioned.  is this it?
link
you'll see near the bottom of the ReadMe is the API properties of the SoccerLineupComponent.  this is where you'll be able to interact properly with the components.  note the OnClick property for Player.  this is how you can connect to your logic.  if this is the repo you meant, can you show where and how you instantiate the SoccerLineupComponent?

@sparkJ Yes this is the one. I added the code near the end where i added the SoccerLineupComponent

for testing, try hardcoding an onClick event in your intial "formation".  you can find out quickly if the click is working at all and possibly if your addNewPlayer logic is correct.
also, should your editNewPlayer function be receiving parameters?  the definition is empty in the above code.

@sparkJ yes you’re right I forgot to add parameters. Also, I will try and see if hard coding it works. Thanks
